# Add columns dynamically and Later Parse values in the respective columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SP which accepts the `Inputtable` as parameter, My `Inputtable` is as shown in the code

```
`create table inputTable ( id int,ItemQty varchar(100))
insert into inputTable(id, ItemQty) values(1,'a,b,c')
insert into inputTable(id, ItemQty) values(2,'x,y')
insert into inputTable(id, ItemQty) values(3,'l,m,n,o,p')
insert into inputTable(id, ItemQty) values(4,'a,b')
insert into inputTable(id, ItemQty) values(5,'m')`
```

and SP i have written is like below

```
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Column_Dynamics] (@tablename varchar(50))

AS
BEGIN

-----
declare @maxcount as int
set @maxcount='select MAX(len(ITEMQTY) - len(replace(ITEMQTY, '','', '''')) +1) from '+@tablename

exec('select MAX(len(ITEMQTY) - len(replace(ITEMQTY, '','', '''')) +1) from '+@tablename)
print @maxcount
exec @maxcount
print @maxcount


declare @var varchar(100)
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM   sys.columns WHERE  object_id = Object_id(@tablename))
set @var='alter table '+ @tablename +' ADD column QTY1'
exec(@var)
select * from @tablename
select max(len(ItemQty))-max(len(replace(ItemQty, ',', ''))-1) from inputtable

END`
```

My table is : [image]

**step 1 )** I want to add the columns dynamically to inputtable like `QTY1,QTY2,QTY3,QTY4,QTY5` because maximum count of ItemQty column is 5, by considering comma as delimiter as shown in figure1

[image]

**step 2) ** Parse values in the respective columns(by considering the delimiter comma (`,`).as shown in figure2

[image]

**Later SP: I got till here, But Not getting the second step, that is update Parse values in the respective columns.**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dynamic_tbl (@tablename varchar(50))

AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @ColumnCount int
DECLARE @rowcount TABLE (Value int);
INSERT INTO @rowcount
EXEC('select MAX(len(ITEMQTY) - len(replace(ITEMQTY, '','', '''')) +1) from '+@tablename);
SELECT @ColumnCount = Value FROM @rowcount;



    Declare @ColumnName nvarchar(10)='qty_'
    Declare @count int =0
    IF(@ColumnCount>0)
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'dyn_tbl'))
        BEGIN
        DROP TABLE dyn_tbl
        END

        select * into dyn_tbl from inputtable 
        SET @count=@count +1;
        WHile(@ColumnCount>=@count) 
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName='qty_'+CONVERT(varchar(2),@count)
            EXEC ('ALTER TABLE dyn_tbl ADD ['+@ColumnName +'] varchar(20)')

            declare @myvar as varchar(max)

            set @myvar='update '+@tablename+' set '+@ColumnName +' =itemQty'

--exec dynamic_tbl 'dyn_tbl'

--select * from dyn_tbl

            --CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(ITEMQTY, ',', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML)
            print @myvar

            exec(@myvar)



            SET @count=@count +1;
        END
    END

----
END
```

Comment: whats the logic for id 2 and id 4, because id 2 is dividing in item qty and and qty1 but id 4 does not

Comment: Ohh sorry, id 4 should divide accordingly..

Comment: Now i changed, Please alter and help me with the code

Answer (score 1):

Procedure to alter given table dynamically based on column length as you have asked

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Column_Dynamics] (@tablename varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
drop table ##temp
declare @query1 varchar(max)
exec ( '
create table ##temp (id int identity,columnsl varchar(100))
declare @maxcount as int
set @maxcount = (select MAX(len(ITEMQTY) - len(replace(ITEMQTY, '','', '''')) +1) from '+@tablename+') 

declare @count int = 1
while (@count <= @maxcount)
begin
declare @colvar nvarchar(100)= ''QTY''
set @colvar = concat(@colvar,@count)
set @count = @count + 1

insert into ##temp select @colvar
end
')

declare @tempstart int = 1
declare @templast int = (select count(*) from ##temp)
declare @updatecol varchar(100) = ''

while (@tempstart <= @templast)
Begin
set @updatecol = (select columnsl from ##temp where id = @tempstart)
exec ('alter table '+@tablename+' Add '+@updatecol+' varchar(100) ')
set @tempstart = @tempstart + 1
end    
End
```

output for inputTable:

```
id  ItemQty    QTY1   QTY2     QTY3   QTY4    QTY5
1   a,b,c      NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
2   x,y        NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   l,m,n,o,p  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   a,b        NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   m          NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

may not be the best way but works.

#### edit

Altered above procedure to perform both actions, Please use below procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Column_Dynamics] (@tablename varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
--  declare @tablename varchar(100) = 'inputTable'
drop table #temp if object_id('temp..#temp') is not null drop table #temp
declare @query1 varchar(max)
create table #temp (id int identity,columnsl varchar(100))
exec ( '
declare @maxcount as int
set @maxcount = (select MAX(len(ITEMQTY) - len(replace(ITEMQTY, '','', '''')) +1) from '+@tablename+') 

declare @count int = 1
while (@count <= @maxcount)
begin
declare @colvar nvarchar(100)= ''QTY''
set @colvar = concat(@colvar,@count)
set @count = @count + 1

insert into #temp
select @colvar

end

')
declare @tempstart int = 1
declare @templast int = (select count(*) from #temp)
declare @updatecol varchar(100) = ''
declare @itemqty varchar(100)

while (@tempstart <= @templast)
Begin
set @updatecol = (select columnsl from #temp where id = @tempstart)
exec ('alter table '+@tablename+' Add '+@updatecol+' varchar(100) ')

set @tempstart = @tempstart + 1
end

declare @sysvar table (id int identity,cols varchar(100))
insert into @sysvar select sys.columns.name AS ColumnName FROM sys.columns JOIN sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id  WHERE sys.tables.name = 'inputTable'

declare @finvar table (id int identity,cols varchar(100))
insert into @finvar select cols from @sysvar where id not in (1,2)

declare @cat int = 1  declare @dog int = (select max(id) from inputTable)

while (@cat <= @dog)
begin
drop table #tab2
if object_id('temp..#tab2') is not null drop table #tab2
create table #tab2 (id int identity,fnvalues varchar(100))

set @itemqty = (select itemqty from inputTable where id = @cat)
insert into #tab2 select item from [dbo].[fnSplit](@itemQty,',')  

declare @cn int = 1 
declare @max int = (select max(id) from #tab2)
declare @sql nvarchar (1000);

while (@cn <= @max)
begin
declare @upcol varchar(100) = (select fnvalues from #tab2 where id = @cn)
declare @plscol varchar(100) = (select cols from @finvar where id = @cn)

set @sql = N'update '+@tablename+' set ' + @plscol + '= '''+@upcol+''' where id = '''+cast(@cat as varchar(10))+''' ';
select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql;

set @cn = @cn + 1

end
set @cat = @cat + 1
End

End
```

output:

```
id  ItemQty    QTY1 QTY2 QTY3   QTY4    QTY5
1   a,b,c       a   b     c      NULL   NULL
2   x,y         x   y     NULL   NULL   NULL
3   l,m,n,o,p   l   m     n      o      p
4   a,b         a   b     NULL   NULL   NULL
5   m           m   NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
```

did not optimize the query but works fine.

Comment: I got this one, but second step updation i am not getting

Comment: not a complete optmized query, i think with less code only it is possible

Answer (score 0):

However, if you have maximum Qty's are known which are in comma separated format then you could use `xml` node method to separate them into `columns`.`QTY1`...`QTY5`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, ITEMQTY,
       a.value('/A[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as QTY1,
       a.value('/A[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as QTY2,
       a.value('/A[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as QTY3,
       a.value('/A[4]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as QTY4,
       a.value('/A[5]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as QTY5
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, ITEMQTY,
           CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(ITEMQTY, ',', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS ITEMQTY1
    FROM inputTable
) A
CROSS APPLY ITEMQTY1.nodes('/A') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
ID  ITEMQTY   QTY1  QTY2    QTY3    QTY4    QTY5
1   a,b,c     a     b       c       NULL    NULL
2   x,y       x     y       NULL    NULL    NULL
3   l,m,n,o,p l     m       n       o       p
4   a,b       a     b       NULL    NULL    NULL
5   m         m    NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Later, you could replace `null` by using `coalesce()` or `isnull()` function with `''`

Comment: Maximum value is unknown. sometimes it depends on inputtable

Comment: is there any other way, i mean other than using xml path

Answer (score 0):

Use This

First Create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split](
@str VARCHAR(MAX),
@delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @returnTable TABLE (idx INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, item VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos INT
SELECT @str = @str + @delimiter
WHILE LEN(@str) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str)
        IF @pos = 1
            INSERT @returnTable (item)
                VALUES (NULL)
        ELSE
            INSERT @returnTable (item)
                VALUES (SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @pos-1))
        SELECT @str = SUBSTRING(@str, @pos+1, LEN(@str)-@pos)       
    END
RETURN
END
GO
```

and use function like this

```
Declare @test TABLE (
ID VARCHAR(200),
Data VARCHAR(200)
)

insert into @test 
(ID, Data)
Values
(1,'a,b,c')


insert into @test 
(ID, Data )
values(2,'x,y')

insert into @test 
(ID, Data )
values(3,'l,m,n,o,p')

insert into @test 
(ID, Data )
values(4,'a,b')

insert into @test 
(ID, Data )
values(5,'m')

select ID,data AS ItemQty,
ISNULL((select item from fn_split(Data,',') where idx in (1)),'') as QTY1 ,
ISNULL((select item from fn_split(Data,',') where idx in (2)),'') as QTY2,
ISNULL((select item from fn_split(Data,',') where idx in (3)),'') as QTY3,
ISNULL((select item from fn_split(Data,',') where idx in (4)),'') as QTY5 ,
ISNULL((select item from fn_split(Data,',') where idx in (5)),'') as QTY5
 from @test
```

Output Same as your Image

[image]

instead of using

```
insert into @test 
(ID, Data)
Values
(1,'a,b,c')
```

you can also assgin it like this

```
insert into @test 
    (ID, Data)
    Values
    (Select Column1, Column2 From YourTable)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it is not that simple, i need it as sp And tablename is always dynamic and also total count may change more that 5 sometimes depending on itemQty column

Comment: and id is never at all the primary key